# Debugging an application in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

I want to debug an application in Linux.
The application is created in C++. The GUI is created using QT.
The GUI is linked with a static library that can be treated as the back end of the application.

I want to debug the static library but am not sure how to do that.

I tried using gdb

```
gdb GUI
```

But how can I attach the library?

Has anyone had experience in debugging libraries in linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gdb will automatically debug functions in the library when they are called. just call it like

```
gdb ./foo
run
```

:) . Be sure you build foo with debugging flags (`-g3` will enable all debugging stuffs for gcc :). You should not optimize when debugging (pass at most `-O1` to gcc, do not optimize further). It can confuse the debugger.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to debug the library code itself, you'll need to build the library with the `-g` compiler flag (as well as building the executable with `-g` as [litb pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320124/debugging-application-in-linux#320136)).  Otherwise gdb will step through your code fine but will throw up its hands each time you make a library call.

Answer (score 2):

You can Try [KDbg](http://www.kdbg.org), [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) - Data Display Debugger, [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Ulike DDD, others are IDE with debugger integrated but core debugger [gdb] remains same in those IDE. only thing is that you will get oragnized view of debugger view in GUI.

Also try Eclipse+CDT pluggin. it's also good.

Answer (score 1):

A little-known alternative is [gdbtui](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_24.html#SEC252) which uses a curses based interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Kdbg or ddd